# How to edit attributes of svg file stored in res folder in android studio

Tags: android, svg, colors

1. Importing an SVG file from res folder
   SVG svg =SVGParser.getSVGFromResource(getResources(),R.raw.one);
   Drawable drawable = svg.createPictureDrawable();
   img3.setImageDrawable(drawable);
2. But I am unable to apply any color filter to that svg using this code
   img3.setColorFilter(Color.parseColor(#3DFFFF));

So I wanted to know whether there is any way of applying the color by editing the attributes of the particular svg file stored in res folder.

I have tried using SVG libraries but they have documentation regarding Eclipse use only.

Answer (score 0):

Apply color before creating drawable using builder.

```
SVG svg = new SVGParser.Builder().setResource(context.getResources(), R.raw.one)
          .replaceColors(SVGColors.mapColor("black") //Put default svg color
                        ,Color.parseColor("#3DFFFF")).build();
```

Comment: I want the user to add the color selected dynamically from an array. The above code would work only once.

Comment: so pass the hex color value in Color.parseColor method.